# python pandas time series year extraction

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF containing timestamps:

```
0     2005-08-31 16:39:40
1     2005-12-28 16:00:34
2     2005-10-21 17:52:10
3     2014-01-28 12:23:15
4     2014-01-28 12:23:15
5     2011-02-04 18:32:34
6     2011-02-04 18:32:34
7     2011-02-04 18:32:34
```

I would like to extract the year from each timestamp, creating additional column in the DF that would look like:

```
0     2005-08-31 16:39:40 2005
1     2005-12-28 16:00:34 2005
2     2005-10-21 17:52:10 2005
3     2014-01-28 12:23:15 2014
4     2014-01-28 12:23:15 2014
5     2011-02-04 18:32:34 2011
6     2011-02-04 18:32:34 2011
7     2011-02-04 18:32:34 2011
```

Obviously I can go over all DF entries stripping off the first 4 characters of the date. Which is very slow. I wonder if there is a fast python-way to do this. 
I saw that it's possible to convert the column into the datetime format by DF = pd.to_datetime(DF,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') but when I try to then apply datetime.datetime.year(DF) it doesn't work. I will also need to parse the timestamps to months and combinations of years-months and so on...
Help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No need to apply a function for each row there is a new [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors) accessor you can call to access the [year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-dt) property:

```
In [35]:

df1['year'] = df1['timestamp'].dt.year
df1
Out[35]:
            timestamp  year
0 2005-08-31 16:39:40  2005
1 2005-12-28 16:00:34  2005
2 2005-10-21 17:52:10  2005
3 2014-01-28 12:23:15  2014
4 2014-01-28 12:23:15  2014
5 2011-02-04 18:32:34  2011
6 2011-02-04 18:32:34  2011
7 2011-02-04 18:32:34  2011
```

If your timestamps are str then you can convert to datetime64 using [`pd.to_dateime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

You can access the months and other attributes using `dt` like the above.

For version prior to `0.15.0` you can perform the following:

```
df1['year'] = df1['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Comment: Thanks, @EdChum, but it doesn't work, giving AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year', although I converted the original DF into datetime64[ns]... I tried to apply DF.year and it is not working...

Comment: No, you do `df['col_name'].dt.year` replace `col_name` with whatever your column name is, also what is your pandas version? I think datetime properties was introduced in `0.15.0`

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt' when I use the original DF with additional column and the above error if I define a new DF1 = pd.to_datetime(DF).. Maybe I should use explicit name rather than the dt abbreviation? :-(

Comment: sorry you have to assign the result of the conversion back or to a new df so `DF = pd.to_datetime(DF)` should work so long as DF is a Series

Comment: type(DF1) (or converted DF if you prefer) is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> and unfortunately it's not working :-( will keep digging...

Comment: So what pandas version are you using? you can find out using `import pandas as pd print(pd.version.version)`

Comment: 0.13.1 you are, of course, right - I need 0.15.2. Thank you.

Comment: For your version the following should work: `df1['year'] = df1['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.year)`